# Filtering Array and displaying in Table View?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

I want to search an dictionary of exercises for the name key and then show the filtered result in the table view. I am using this function

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    let filtered = exercises.filter { $0["name"] == searchText }
    print(filtered)

    if(filtered.count == 0){
        searchActive = false;
    } else {
        searchActive = true;
    }
    self.exercisesTableView.reloadData()
}
```

Variables:

```
var exercises = [Exercise]()
var filtered: [NSMutableArray] = []
var searchActive: Bool = false
```

In the search function I get the error

> Type'Exercise' has no subscript members

and then i have the issue that the result is an NSMutableArray and so I cant set the result names as cell text to display

> Cannot convert value of type 'NSMutableArray' to type 'String' in coercion

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
    if (searchActive){
        cell.textLabel?.text = filtered[indexPath.row] as String
    } else {
        let exercise = exercises[indexPath.row]

        cell.textLabel!.text = exercise.name
    }
    return cell
}
```

Here is my Exercise dictionary for reference:

```
final public class Exercise {
    var id: Int
    var descrip: String
    var name: String
    var muscles: [Int]
    var equipment: [Int]

    public init?(dictionary: [String: Any]) {

        guard
            let id = dictionary["id"] as? Int,
            let descrip = dictionary["description"] as? String,
            let name = dictionary["name"] as? String,
            let muscles = dictionary["muscles"] as? [Int],
            let equipment = dictionary["equipment"] as? [Int]

            else { return nil }

        self.id = id
        self.descrip = descrip
        self.name = name
        self.muscles = muscles
        self.equipment = equipment

    }
```

I can fix the second error by making var filtered: [String] = [] so it can be used as a cell title, but that doesnt resolve the first error and im not sure is the right way to go about it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `filtered` also type of `[Exercise]` and you need to filter it like.

```
var filtered = [Exercise]() 

self.filtered = exercises.filter { $0.name == searchText }
```

Here `$0` is type of `Exercise` object, so you need to access its property name using `$0.name`.

**Edit:** If you want `filtered` as type of `[String]` with only name then you can need to use both `map` and `filter` like this.

```
self.filtered = exercises.filter { $0.name == searchText }.map { $0.name }
```

OR

```
self.filtered = exercises.map { $0.name }.filter { $0 == searchText }
```

OR directly using `filterMap` as @dfri suggested.

```
self.filtered = exercises.flatMap{ $0.name == searchText ? $0.name : nil }
```

Comment: Thanks for this, however if i set filtered to also = [Exercise]() how am i meant to map it to the cell name when its not a string anymore? see the part of my code             cell.textLabel?.text = filtered[indexPath.row] as String

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't like it, do i need to edit the variable too or just insert the stated code? Errors are Cannot convert value of type 'String' to closure result type 'Exercise'  and in the table cell name statement: Cannot convert value of type 'Exercise' to type 'String' in coercion

Comment: @NiravD note that an common alternative to using chained `filter` and `map` operation is a single `flatMap` operation: `self.filtered = exercises.flatMap{ $0.name == searchText ? $0.name : nil }`.

Comment: @infernouk Yes, now you need to change `filtered` as `[String]` already write in `Edit` line check properly.

Comment: @dfri Edited answer for that, Thnx for great suggestion.

Comment: Its loading without errors now, however as soon as i click anything in the emulator to search im getting a fatal crash with this info, is this related?  *** Assertion failure in -[UISearchResultsTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3600.5.2/UITableView.m:6593
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier Cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

Comment: Thats what i thought, but its 100% set as Cell so i couldnt pin point why its crashing

Comment: yep as it shows the unfiltered data in the same cell without issues, its just when i try and search it crashes, heres a imgur link to show the cell identifier in place http://i.imgur.com/AnkGPcn.png

Comment: @infernouk Filtering to a different type as the source type is not recommended, because it requires an (actually unnecessary) additional step to map the type which could be expensive in a large data base.

Comment: I added the recipient to make clear that I didn't meant you ;-) @NiravD

Comment: its when typing, you can click search and load the keyboard, but clicking any letter crashes the app with the stated debug

Comment: numberof is as follows:     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if(searchActive) {
            return filtered.count
        } else {
            return exercises.count
        }
    }

Comment: Im a bit confused, I have a SearchDisplayController but im using searchBar via IBOutlet in my view controller file? I have both

Comment: Both are differently work, you just need UIsearchbar, so remove `SearchDisplayController` and add just UISearchbar in your interface builder and connect the outlet again.

Comment: Thanks I got it working by deleting the controller and making the outlet!

Answer (score 5):

I told you yesterday *forget the dictionary semantics* when using a custom class.
Do not use key subscripting!

As mentioned in the other answers you have to declare `filtered` also as `[Exercise]`

```
var filtered = [Exercise]()
```

and filter

```
self.filtered = exercises.filter { $0.name == searchText }
```

However if you want to search also for partial strings use

```
self.filtered = exercises.filter {$0.name.range(of: searchText, options: [.anchored, .caseInsensitive, .diacriticInsensitive]) != nil }
```

**But**

since both filtered and unfiltered arrays are of type `[Exercise]` you have to change `cellForRowAtIndexPath` this way

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
    let exercise : Exercise 
    if (searchActive){
        exercise = filtered[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        exercise = exercises[indexPath.row]
    }
    cell.textLabel!.text = exercise.name
    return cell
}
```

Comment: thanks ive tried this out as it does seem cleaner to keep the filter the same type, no errors just im still getting this odd crash when typing a letter into the search bar as mentioned in Nirav's response comments

Comment: Are you using `UISearchController`? If yes use `searchResultController.isActive` to check the search state rather than a custom boolean variable.

Comment: so i need to declare searchResultController as a variable? just swapping it out for searchResultController.isActive causes unresolved identifier errors. I have     let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil) at the moment

Comment: Yes, of course `var searchResultController: UISearchController!` But then you should use also `updateSearchResults(for` rather than `textDidChange`

Comment: I have updated to searchResultController.isActive however this now causes the fatal crash just upon clicking the search field before even typing. for changing to updateSearchResults, how does it fit into the textDidChange statement?     func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String)

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is `$0["name"] == searchText`. `$0` in this context is of `Excersise` type and you refer to it as it's an array. This line should look like this:

`let filtered = exercises.filter { $0.name == searchText }`

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have used the following code in some personal projects, the code is very similar to the previous answers. I just use `contains`.

```
func filter(query: String){
        if query.isEmpty {
            self.filteredData = self.originalData
        } else {
            self.filteredData = self.originalData.filter {
                $0.prop1!.lowercased().contains(query)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

## Clean & Effective Approach

Declare these arrays in your class:

```
var filteredData: [Exercise] = []  
{
    didSet
    { 
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

// once we get our data, we will put it into filtered array
// user will interact only with filtered array
var source: [Exercise] = [] 
{
    didSet
    { 
        filteredData = source
    }
}
```

Implement you function as follows:

```
extension ViewController: UISearchBarDelegate
{
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String)
    {        
        let searchText = searchText.lowercased()
        let filtered = source.filter({ $0.lowercased().contains(searchText) })
        filteredData = filtered.isEmpty ? source : filtered
    }
}
```

You will notice that the user will never interact with the original array, but the filtered array.

```
// MARK: UITableViewDataSource

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return filteredData.count
}

// MARK: UITableViewDelegate

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    .
    .

    cell.textLabel?.text = filteredData[indexPath.row]
}
```